# How to pass first item unit price to dataLayer in cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm setting up a dataLayer in the WooCommerce cart trying to pass the first item value to it. The code below passes both the values as one variable and that's not what I want - I want an array to be built for each item in the cart.

One array for the prices, and one for the quantity.

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({

  'firstItemUnitPrice': '<?php
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

    foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
        $_product = $values['data']->post;
        $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
        echo $price;
    }?>'
});

</script>
```

The output from the code above is:

firstItemunitprice: 1144

There are two products in cart, one worth $11 and one $44.

I know how to separate them but I want them to be added as an array to the dataLayer. Help please?

I understand I need to loop through the cart, but I want each item price and each item quantity to be placed in a dataLayer.